# Java: Hashmap with contents compiled

Tags: java, hashmap

I am looking to implement a HashMap with its contents in the bytecode. This would be similar to me serializing the content and then reading it in. But in my experience serialization only works with saving it to a file and then reading it in, I would want this implementation to be faster than that.

Comment: What exact problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Did you mean byte array instead of byte code? Bytecode is what your java code becomes after you compile it

Comment: I'm trying to make a class whose time for initialization and lookup is as small as possible. My thoughts were to output a .java file with the data written into that, and then compile that file into bytecode.

Comment: My interest was triggered by a lecture on perfect static hashing. With this there are two levels of hashing, and you can rehash until every item has its own table element in the second level table. This means the theoretical worst time complexity is `O(1)`. So my thoughts were, if the content is static and known before compile time, what is the method method of doing this for speed of lookup (and class initialization).

Answer (score 3):

> But in my experience serialization only works with saving it to a file and then reading it in, I would want this implementation to be faster than that.

Serialization works with *streams*. Specifically, [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) can wrap any [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html). If you want to perform in-memory serialization, you could use [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) here.

Similarly on the input side.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your HashMap as byte array using Java Serialization mechanizm

```
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put(1, 1);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bout);
    oos.writeObject(map);
    oos.close();
    byte[] bytes = bout.toByteArray();
    // restore from bytes
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    map = (Map) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(map);
```

output

```
{1=1}
```

not that both keys and values in the Map must be Serializable otherwise it wont work

Comment: Thank you. I would output a java file with the data in as a string and then deserialzate it. How would this method compare to making my own HashMap class which has the table (with values) as static variables in that?